# NSStringWithFormat Crash

Tags: ios, nsstring, stringwithformat

Simply stated, the following code has me baffled as to why it should fail.

```
// This line works
NSString * string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]];

// This line works
string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"somestring"];

// This line generates and EXEC_BAD_ACCESS error
string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu%@",[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970],@"somestring"];
```

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Value returned by `[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]` is of type `NSTimeInterval` which is of type  `typedef double NSTimeInterval;` you are printing `unsigned int`. Replace `@"%lu%@"` with `@"%f%@"` and will be ok.

Comment: Or you could cast it to an int i.e. `@"%lu%@", (unsigned int) NSDate.date.timeIntervalSince1970` - though this comment is just for completeness; I'd do what the answer says :)

Comment: That will not cause a crash though, just generate an unsigned version of the return date, which is the intention for my purposes.

Comment: @sch - you don't know what's happening to the stack as a side effect of passing in the wrong format specifier :) I suspect it's not working in both cases but the damage is done in a safe section of memory in case (1) but in memory you then try to use in case (2).